# Google Spread Sheet Import Question

Tags: google-sheets, google-search

I have some Google dorks like (Around 4000+)
"site:uber.com"
site:twitter.com"
What I want is to fetch results/links of each search on Google.
Is there any way?
I add url like that and it returns me result:
https://www.google.com/search?q=site:uber.com

Comment: Not understanding your question. What exactly does "fetch results/links of each search on Google" mean? For ex do you have "site:uber.com" in a cell and you want to get "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:uber.com" in another cell? Or do you want to go to "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:uber.com" and grab the first 10 search results?

Comment: Yes i  want to go to "google.com/search?q=site:uber.com" and grab the first 10 search results.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Would you please edit your question to include a summary of the research that you've done on this topic. Have you read [Performing Google Search In Spreadsheet And Scraping The SERP Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43020013/1330560) or [Can importXML() Be Used to Scrape Data from SERPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54997877/1330560) on StackOverflow. Have you looked at the various add-ons that are available for this?